# Making a timer in HTML that retains the countdown even after terminating the programn

Tags: javascript, html

Essentially, I wish to make a website in HTML and an element I wish to include is a countdown timer along with button. Upon the click of a button the timer would begin and the button would be unusable during said duration (24 hours).

I have made a function like this in html, but the issue I face is that if I close the program the timer gets reset and the button is still usable. The reason why this is crucial is that the button performs another function which isn't really important right now but the function can only be accessed by the user every 24 hours only. Is there a way to solve this problem?

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Countdown Timer</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="timer">01:00</h1>
    <button id="start-btn" onclick="startTimer()">Start</button>

    <script>
      var timer = document.getElementById("timer");
      var startBtn = document.getElementById("start-btn");
      var time = 60; // 1 minute in seconds

      function countdown() {
        var minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
        var seconds = time % 60;

        var minutesStr = minutes.toString().padStart(2, "0");
        var secondsStr = seconds.toString().padStart(2, "0");

        timer.innerHTML = minutesStr + ":" + secondsStr;

        if (time > 0) {
          time--;
          setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
        } else {
          startBtn.disabled = false;
        }
      }

      function startTimer() {
        time = 60;
        startBtn.disabled = true;
        countdown();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will need to store the initial start time somewhere, for example in localStorage. Then you can read it back from there when the page loads, and do the necessary math.

Comment: _"The reason why this is crucial is that the button performs another function which isn't really important right now but the function can only be accessed by the user every 24 hours only."_ - if this is absolutely vital, then you will have to ensure it some other way though. Any user can go and "overwrite" your disabling of the button on the client side, or call whatever functionality the disabled buttons was supposed to trigger, directly.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

### client-side solution

You can save the start date/time into the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) of your users browser and check against it when the site is reopend. If the time is over you can delete the enrtry.

Do note that users can willingly or unwillingly reset the timer. Either by clearing their browsing data or pressing **F12** and then navigating to localStorage and editing the entries.

### server-side solution

This is a more complicated solution, but it is not as easy to be falsified by the user.

You will need a database. There, you insert the user's IP and the datetime when the button is pressed.

Whenever the user visits the site, you can access the start time and "continue" the countdown.

Depending on your database size and expected traffic, you should also set up a job to delete all entries older than the time the button should be blocked, as they are no longer required.

Do note that this means that you collect *personal data* in form of the IP, meaning you will have to conform with a bunch of [legal requirements](https://gdpr-info.eu/issues/personal-data/).